# Almost all memory is used up by files symply classified as "Other". How do I fix it?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage

Currently using an HTC Desire 510 with Android 4.4.3
It has a total of roughly 3.8 GB interal storage (not counting application storage). But about 3GB are occupied by what the phone considers "Other files", not letting me see which files those are.

When I connected to a PC through USB I did find a file named ".thumbdata" in DCIM/.thumbnails weighting over 2GB, which I immediately deleted. The empty space in my phone remained unchanged, so I restarted it a couple of times. The file reappeared, now weighting just 30MB, but the source of those used up 2GB is nowhere to be found. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

.thumbdata is nothing but the thumbnails of the images in your gallery. They are cached into the .thumbdata file.

Other than that, most of the space will be occupied by Apps installed in your phone.

Try clearing the cache of every app that you use and uninstall the apps that you don't need.

Try using [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) to analyse the files in your phone and get a detailed view of large files, duplicate files, junk files, etc.

Comment: The only large file I had was a 50MB video I did not transfer to the PC yet. All duplicates were deleted, weighting ~20MB total. Junk filed were only 900KB.

Comment: Already deleted every single detetable app from the phone just to update Youtube yesterday. Almost all of them were on external storage anyway. Internal storage stays unchanged. ES states the same thing, 83% of all files are written as "Other" and can't be viewed.

Comment: were you using ES from before ? ES actually has a Recycle Bin option. So the deleted files go and stay in the Recycle Bin. Maybe try cleaning them.

Answer (score 0):

In section other is showing that uses space in my case that happens i multiple situations:
When there is files in .zip or any other format that is not music readable document or such
Aslo sometimes when apps stored some files downloaded trought them an files stored in Android folder, that was counted into other in storage settings
Sometimes when .mp3 files wasn't stored into "Music" folder they was counted as other
And finally cache not whole but good part of it was counted into other but when I clean cache with tapping on cache in storage settings that cache was cleared.
Now about .thumbdata files, thoose files mostly creates by stock gallery app, sometimes it's being created when you send some picture from for example from viber, so try disabling stock gallery app and deleting those files. 
In my expirience happened that file manager shows that .thumbdata file weights 2gb but when I delete it storage doesn't show 2 more GB free but file is gone.
Use ccleaner app and clear cache and other junk it should delete .thumbdata too.